# NHibernate one-to-many mapping throws NullReferenceException when serialized

Tags: c#, wcf, nhibernate

When I call a WCF operation from the WCF test client the client throws an exception `The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.`

In the WCF tracelog I see that an NullReferenceException is thrown when the WCF service was responding to the client.

`NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag 1.get_Count()
WriteArrayOfCDekkingErToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )`

The one to many mapping of CDekking for the class CVerzekerde:

```
<bag name="Dekkingen" table="CDEKKZORGDETAIL" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true" lazy="false">
            <key>
                <column name="DPOLSSEQ"/>
                <column name="MUTSEQ"/>
                <column name="DPRODSEQ"/>
                <column name="DVOBJSEQ"/>
            </key>          
            <one-to-many class="CDekking"/>
        </bag>
```

The key many to one mapping for the CDekking class:

```
<key-many-to-one name="Verzekerde" class="CVerzekerde" lazy="false">
                <column name="DPOLSSEQ"/>
                <column name="MUTSEQ"/>
                <column name="DPRODSEQ"/>
                <column name="DVOBJSEQ"/>
            </key-many-to-one>
```

I have no idea why the null reference exception is thrown. The list of Dekkingen in Verzekerde is not empty. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Equals/GetHashCode implementations based on that key columns.